# Xmarks sync crashing firefox

Tags: firefox, xmarks

I recently had to re-install firefox and chrome. I then re-installed xmarks in both browsers. Now xmarks crashes firefox on sync.

I'm running Windows 7 (up to date to the day)
Firefox 30.0
Xmarks 4.3.3

I've tried many types of remove xmarks, reinstall xmarks, reset all about:config settings, remove all xmarks related files from profile. Etc. In other words, I've tried to make my install as clean as possible, but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an old account that I think was trying to download a set of bookmarks that was too large. That's my only explanation. When I switched to a newer and smaller set it synced fine.

Comment: I posted a ticket to x-marks, and they got back to me that there was actually an error in my database, which they fixed!